# JQuery Mexican Wave Style Table Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible using JQuery to create a table animation in which each row of the table body comes in with a delay from the next row with a fade?

Let's say we have a table with a width of 500px, the first row would appear at around 50-100px mark from the left fading into view and moving into position. When this row has moved lets say 25px, the next row does the same and the next for the entire table.

### Update

Okay, so it looks like my 'question' has been taken litural and I haven't been more to the point other than 'is it possible?...'.

I know about .animate(); and use it quite often, however more to the point, to loop through a table giving in a slide effect to each table row with a delay per next row is something else.

How can I loop through all table rows and apply an animation with a delay to the next table row?

Comment: If that is the question then the answer is simply 'Yes'. Maybe you can help by sharing what have you tried / explored?

Comment: *"Is it possible"* ... sure. That simply isn't a valid question here. Nobody is going to build this for you...the idea here is you try it and when you run into problems bring your code and ask questions then

Comment: Look at the jquery animate() docs.  You can animate numeric css properties like left in your case.  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Updated question, sorry for not being specific